# Is is possible to take accept JSON objects in the body of a POST request without having getter and setter methods?

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs, dropwizard

I need to accept JSON data in the body of a POST request. Is is possible to accept all the input JSON data that is present in the body of POST method without defining the getter and setter methods for all the keys in the JSON objects ?

```
@POST
@Path("/post")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public postData GiveData(final postData output) {
    return output;
}
```

My Get and Set methods ::

```
public class TestClass {

   @JsonProperty("Type")
    public String getType() {
            return Type;
    }

    public void setType(String Type) {
            this.Type = Type;
    }
}
```

If JSON input is

```
{
  Type : "Test"
}

 Returns 200 :
```

But If the JSON input is

```
{
  "Type" : "Test" ,
  "Random-KeY" : "Value" 
} 

 Returns 400 : Unable to Process JSON data
```

My problem is I need to accept data where we cannot expect the incoming JSON keys , so I cannot write get and set methods for all the keys, So how can I accept all the JSON objects in the body of the POST Method. 
Any Suggestion could help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can mark your Class with

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

This will Map only existing fields in the class and ignores remaining.

Comment: @John ,can you please clear your requirement?  If you want to accept  all data of the json object but you don't want to declare `getters setter` , only the field name? or you want to exclude both of them?
I think if that is what I stated, then it's not possible to accept, as you have to map those keys to get a particular field's value, hence declare those fields you are going to get them.

Comment: please check  my answer if that helps

Answer (score 0):

As you have unknown key/values in your json data, I suggest to use HashMap for requestbody which will server what you are wanting(i.e. no getter,setter and accept unknown values) like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/post")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public postData GiveData(@RequestBody HashMap<String, Object> dataHashMap) {
       //access the values by their keynames. You know how to get keySet of hashMap and  
       // iterate over them(I guess)
        return output;
    }
```

Hope this will work.